# JDBC (jTDS) and Mac OSX App with Xcode 4.3

Tags: sql, sql-server, xcode, macos

I am a new Mac OSX app developer who is in the process of learning Xcode and the vagaries of OSX development. Skip the rest of this paragraph and jump to the next one if you want. Just a little background - I have been in the computer field in one way or another for the past 30 years, a software developer for 25 years. I'm making the transition from Windows development tools to OSX.

OK - I am writing a simple (?) OSX app which will run on a Mac Mini Server. The server will act as "middleware" between iPad iOS apps and a Windows-based MS SQL Server database on Windows Server 2008,

I decided to work with the jTDS driver from SourceForge. I downloaded the SQuirreL OSX app which allows you to pick an SQL driver, set the necessary parameters and connect to the database. Worked like a champ ! I want to do the same thing with my app, but I don't know how to include the .jar file in my app and then load it abd run it. I would appreciate pointers to appropriate documentation and especially source code samples. There is a doc file on using Java ODBC  drivers with Xcode, but it is out of date and no longer applies to the current incarnation of Xcode.

Any help would be much appreciated, especially the source code samples. TIA and best regards to all of ny fellow OSX developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load a class in Java withouth having it on the (initial) classpath.

You need to create a URLClassloader with the .jar file in question, load the class and create a new instance. Using that instance you can then create a new connection.

Something like

```
URL[] libs = new URL[1];
File jarFile = new File("/path/to/jtds.jar");
libs[0] = jarFile.toURI().toURL();

URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(libs, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()); 

Class drvClass = this.classLoader.loadClass("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");

Driver drv = (Driver)drvClass.newInstance();
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("user", "my_db_user");
props.put("password", "very_secret_password");

Connection con = drv.connect("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://someserver", props);
```

As an alternative, I think you can also register the instance with the DriverManager and then call DriverManager.getConnection(). But I'm not entirely sure if that works. Calling `connect()` directly on the Driver instance definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

It worked in SQL Squirrel because you put the JAR in its /lib directory and started it up.  SQL Squirrel is a Java Swing app.  It assumes that all the JARs in its /lib directory are in the CLASSPATH, so when the Java JVM starts up it finds the jTDS driver JAR and Bob's your uncle.

You have to do something similar with X-code: tell it where to find 3rd party JARs and put the jTDS JAR there.

I'm a bit confused on one detail: you wrote "Java ODBC drivers."  Did you mean "Java JDBC drivers"?